# Adding new item to naviguation properties doesn't create incremental int PK

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Here's the situation :

I have a server that creates machine programs for parts. My infrastructure looks like the following :

- WillyDemandes : Request to create the programs for a part
- WillyMachines (Related to WillyDemandes by FK): Every machine program
  created for this part.
- WillyResults (Related to WillyMachines by FK)    : Every warnings,
  results, outputs for a machine.

The servers pulls the first WillyDemandes to process :

```
    static public WillyDemandes GetFirst()
    {

        WillyDemandes willyDemandes;

        using (Info_IndusContext db = new Info_IndusContext())
        {
                willyDemandes = db.WillyDemandes
                    .Include(x => x.IdPartNavigation)
                    .Where(x => x.Statut == Statuts.EnTest.ToString() && x.Username == Environment.UserName)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Priority)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

            if (willyDemandes != null)
            {
                willyDemandes.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString();
                willyDemandes.ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
                willyDemandes.DateDebut = DateTime.Now;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return willyDemandes;

    }
```

Then the server adds a new machine to the part (new WillyMachines to WillyDemandes)

```
    static public WillyMachines Create(WillyDemandes willyDemandes, string MachineName)
    {
        using (Info_IndusContext db = new Info_IndusContext())
        {
            WillyMachines willyMachines = willyDemandes.WillyMachines.Where(x => x.DocumentType == MachineName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (willyMachines == null)
            {
                willyMachines = new WillyMachines() { IdDemande = willyDemandes.Id, DocumentType = MachineName };
                willyDemandes.WillyMachines.Add(willyMachines);
            }

            willyMachines.DateDebut = DateTime.Now;
            willyMachines.DateFin = null;
            willyMachines.Performance = null;
            willyMachines.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString();
            db.SaveChanges();

            return willyMachines;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that whenever I do the previous code, SaveChanges says that the context hasn't changed and the ID of willyMachines stays at 0 instead of grabbing the incremental ID that the DB should give him. Therefore, I did the following patch as a workaround (add to context.WillyMachines instead of naviguation property and refresh WillyDemandes)

```
    static public WillyMachines Create(WillyDemandes willyDemandes, string MachineName)
    {
        using (Info_IndusContext db = new Info_IndusContext())
        {
            WillyMachines willyMachines = willyDemandes.WillyMachines.Where(x => x.DocumentType == MachineName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (willyMachines == null)
            {
                willyMachines = new WillyMachines() { IdDemande = willyDemandes.Id, DocumentType = MachineName };
                db.WillyMachines.Add(willyMachines);
            }

            willyMachines.DateDebut = DateTime.Now;
            willyMachines.DateFin = null;
            willyMachines.Performance = null;
            willyMachines.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString();
            db.SaveChanges();
            willyDemandes = WillyDemandesController.Refresh(willyDemandes);
            return willyMachines;
        }
    }

    static public WillyDemandes Refresh(WillyDemandes willyDemandes)
    {
        using (Info_IndusContext db = new Info_IndusContext())
        {
            return db.WillyDemandes
                    .Include(x => x.IdPartNavigation)
                    .Include(x => x.WillyMachines).ThenInclude(x => x.WillyResults)
                    .Where(x => x.Id == willyDemandes.Id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Why isn't my context seeing changes to WillyDemandes? Should I Attach WillyDemandes to the context beforehand? Should I go for something else? Is my solution viable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first case no object was added to the context. `willyDemandes` is just a variable that contains a `null` if no record is found. Setting the variable to something doesn't modify anything other than the *pointer* stored in that memory location.

The first snippet is equivalent to :

```
        WillyMachines willyMachines = willyDemandes.WillyMachines
                                                   .Where(x => x.DocumentType == MachineName)
                                                   .FirstOrDefault();
        if (willyMachines == null)
        {
            var otherMachines = new WillyMachines{ 
               IdDemande = willyDemandes.Id, 
               DocumentType = MachineName 
               WillyMachines.Add(willyMachines);            
               DateDebut = DateTime.Now;
               DateFin = null;
               Performance = null;
               Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString()
           };
       }
       db.SaveChanges();
```

New objects should be added to the context with `db.WillyMachines.Add(willyMachines);` :